# Spawning enemies in four different positions with a fixed trajectory in android game

Tags: java, android, andengine, android-studio

This is my first android game, I appreciate all the help. I want to define 4 spawning zones starting from out of the screen (left, right, up and down). Enemies coming from this areas have a fixed trajectory to the center, when this enemies come into the screen the player can move them to a specific corner, but if it lets go of it a new trajectory has to be calculated so it keeps moving to the center.

I am having trouble thinking on how to define this 4 areas, there is also 4 types enemies (they are the same, but they have a different color), should I place this 4 enemies on an arrayList ?. If I know how to define this 4 spawning areas which randomly decides where to spawn I then don't exactly know how to define the fixed trajectory to the center. Also, need to lower the speed to a more adecuate one. (Sorry if this seems like a lot am asking)

Current code looks like this (I am using AndEngine library):

```
public class gameEscene extends baseScene {

    // Regions for images
    private ITextureRegion BackgroundRegion;
    private ITextureRegion Corner;
    private ITextureRegion Center;
    private ITextureRegion Marco;
    // Sprites
    private Sprite spriteBackground;
    private Sprite spriteCorner;
    private Sprite spriteCenter;
    private Sprite spriteMarco;


    //  Enemies
    private ArrayList<Enemies> listEnemies;
    private ITextureRegion regionEnemy;
    //  Time to generate enemies
    private float timeEnemies = 0;              //  Counter
    private float   TIME_LIMIT  =   2.5f;       //  Every 2.5s it creates


    @Override
    public void loadResources() {
        BackgroundRegion = loadImage("black.jpg");
       Corner = loadImage("Corner_T.png");
        Center = loadImage("Center.png");
        Marco = loadImage("m.png");
        regionEnemy = loadimage("ship.png");
    }

    private void createEnemies() {
        for (int x = 700; x <= 1200; x += 100) {
            for (int y = 100; y <= 700; y += 100) {
                Sprite ship = loadSprite(x, y, regionEnemy);
                attachChild(ship);
                Enemies enemy = new Enemies(ship);
                listEnemies.add(enemy);
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void createScene() {
        listEnemies = new ArrayList<>();
        spriteBackground = loadSprite(GameControl.CAMARA_WIDTH/2, GameControl.CAMARA_HEIGHT/2, BackgroundRegion);
        spriteCorner = loadSprite(GameControl.CAMARA_WIDTH/2, GameControl.CAMARA_HEIGHT/2, Corner);
        spriteCenter = loadSprite(GameControl.CAMARA_WIDTH/2, GameControl.CAMARA_HEIGHT/2, Center);
        spriteMarco = loadSprite(GameControl.CAMARA_WIDTH/2, GameControl.CAMARA_HEIGHT/2, Marco);
        attachChild(spriteBackground);
        attachChild(spriteCorner);
        attachChild(spriteCenter);
        attachChild(spriteMarco);
        createEnemies();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackKeyPressed() {
        // Regresar al menú principal
        admScenes.createMenuScenes();
        admScenes.setScene(SceneType.MENU_SCENE);
        admScene.liberateGameScene();
    }

    @Override
    public sceneType getSceneType() {
        return sceneType.GAME_SCENE;
    }

    @Override
    public void liberateScene() {
        this.detachSelf();
        this.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void liberateResources() {
       BackgroundRegion.getTexture().unload();
        Corner.getTexture().unload();
        Center.getTexture().unload();
        Marco.getTexture().unload();
        regionEnemy.getTexture().unload();
        BackgroundRegion = null;
        Corner = null;
        Center = null;
        Marco = null;
        regionEnemy = null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onManagedUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed)   {

        super.onManagedUpdate(pSecondsElapsed);
        timeEnemies +=  pSecondsElapsed;        //  Acumulates time
        if  (timeEnemies>TIME_LIMIT)    {   //  Time has completed
            tiemeEnemies    =   0;
            Sprite spriteEnemy  =   loadSprite(GameControl.CAMARA_WIDTH+regionEnemy.getWidth(),
                    (float)(Math.random()*GameControl.CAMARA_HEIGHT-regionEnemy.getHeight())    +
                            regionEnemy.getHeight(),regionEnemy);

            Enemies newEnemy = new Enemies(spriteEnemies);
            //newEnemies.mover(0,10);
            listEnemies.add(newEnemy);  //  Adds it to the scene
            attachChild(newEnemy.getSpriteEnemy()); //  Adds it to the list
        }

        //  Updates every enemy and sees if any has gotten out of the screen
        for (int    i=listEnemies.size()-1; i>=0;   i--)    {
            Enemies enemy   =   listEnemies.get(i);
            enemy.mover(-10, 0);
            if  (enemy.getSpriteEnemy().getX()<-enemy.getSpriteEnemy().getWidth())  {
                detachChild(enemy.getSpriteEnemy());        //  Deletes it from the scene
                listEnemies.remove(enemy);                                                                  //  eliminates it from the list
            }
            //  Checks the collision of enemy with another sprite

            if  (spriteCenter.collidesWith(enemy.getSpriteEnemy())) {
                detachChild(enemy.getSpriteEnemy());
                //enemies.remove(enemy);

            }
        }
    }

}
```

`Enemies` class looks like this:

```
public class Enemies {

    private Sprite sprite;

    public Enemies(Sprite sprite) {
        this.sprite = sprite;
    }

    public Sprite getSpriteEnemy() {
        return sprite;
    }

    public void setSprite(Sprite sprite) {
        this.sprite = sprite;
    }

    public void mover(int dx, int dy) {
        sprite.setPosition( sprite.getX()+dx, sprite.getY()+dy );
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Edit: Screenshot of idea

[image: Game concept]

Comment: I'm finding it hard to visualise your problem. Could you perhaps draw it, or post an annotated screenshot?

Comment: Sure, I put an image of the idea above. So, enemies will be coming from this 4 areas (coming from outside the screen), with a fixed trajectory to the center image/sprite, the user has to move them to their corresponding color, if the player doesn't place if in the corresponding color and drops it on a blank space, it still has to recalculate trajectory to the center. Sorry If my idea didn't come thru, and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you are not saving the enemies locations in their class, try using a `random` to generate Their location (from presets ranges) and then using ArrayLists and Itteraters together to spawn and ammend their positions?